# Unix console becomes inactive after closing vim

Tags: unix, command-line

```
user@laptop:~$ locate file.ext | xargs vim -p
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
2 files to edit
user@laptop:~$
```

After finding files and modifying them in vim I want to save them and continue to work in unix console but I can't do that.

After vim close console just halts. No activity on any keypress. The only workaround is to close console tab and create a new one.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

try to run it different way:

```
vim -p `locate file.ext`
```

or you can try to run `reset` command after your vim session, to reset terminal options to defaults:

```
locate file.ext | xargs vim -p; reset
```

Comment: please accept an answer by putting a checkmark sign under it if it helped you. thank you

Comment: Don't use the second one, it's a hack; the first command is the idiomatic and correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do, after exiting vim from a piped command on Cygwin.

```
stty sane {enter}
```

Of course, you won't see that get typed, but after you hit enter, the tty will come back to life. It's a pain, but works.

I don't like the other solution here because often I am running a much more complex lookup than a file lookup. I might do something like this:

```
egrep -ri [pattern] * | sed -e 's:\:.*::g' | grep -v ^Binary | sort | uniq | xargs vim
```

In my work (10 year old fast moving codebase), this kind of search is so common that I have the first five commands in a single shell script that I pipe to vim.

Comment: Couldn't you do `vim $(callToBashScript)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

A pipe is not a terminal as such, but have you tried `fg`?

Comment: fg what? there is no background job here

Comment: Tried the exact same line in my terminal and got a running Vim process accesible via fg.

Comment: Matias, can you please share your command? I haven't heard of fg before. How can I use it?

Comment: "fg" means foreground, swapping a paused process from background to foreground in your terminal. Try "man bash", then pause it by Ctrl-Z. Then issue "fg".

Comment: It isn't running in the background, its standard input is attached to the pipe from locate, thus "Input is not from a terminal" is accurate.